# Linear Indexing using Compute Shader

Tags: c#, directx-11, sharpdx, compute-shader

I'm using compute shaders to do some stuff. I create an input buffer (which is 1-dimensional) of a particular length and then call a dispatch on x and y in order to optimize computation time. But I've problem accessing the indexes. What could be the problem?

```
double size = Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(input.pattern.Length));
shader.Start((int)Math.Ceiling(size/32), (int)Math.Ceiling(size / 32), 1);
```

And in hlsl code...

```
[numthreads(32, 32, 1)]
void Reconstruction(uint3 dispatchThreadID : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    int idx = dispatchThreadID.y * size + dispatchThreadID.x;
    if (idx > rayCount) { return; }
```

I print the idx but some are repeated and I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of dimensions in the thread grouping is used more as a convenience than an optimization. Under the hood, it will all shake out to being about the same. So for a 1D buffer, you'd be no worse off using something like

```
[numthreads(64, 1, 1)]
void Reconstruction(uint3 dispatchThreadID : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    int idx = dispatchThreadID.x;
    // ... etc ...
}
```

than what you have above. You also get the added benefit that you end up doing less computation in your shader since you'll automagically get the correct indices passed in through the `SV_` parameter.

The only optimization you should be keeping in mind is that the total number of threads in a group should ideally be a multiple of 64. This is because at the hardware level, AMD GPUs generally work with "waves" of 64 threads at a time. NVidia is (if I recall correctly) 32, which still works out. If you used (say) 32 then you'd get 50% utilization on AMD which is not cool.